# Custom aligning multiple images

Tags: html, css, image, layout, css-float

I am new to CSS and I am working on a school project. I seem to be having trouble aligning images. This is what it's supposed to look like:
[image]

This is a layout I did on Photoshop, what I'm doing is I crop the images and import them to my html file. I am importing two images right now and I am having trouble aligning the two of them:

[image]

this is my HTML code:

```
    <a href=""><img src="Zotac_1.png" class="gpu"></a>
    <a href=""><img src="webcam.png" class="webcam"></a>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
.gpu {
margin-top: 10px;
float: left;
}

.webcam {
float: left;
margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

Sorry for the long post

Comment: try adding universal selector at the top of css code `*{margin:0px auto;}` or try specifying width and height for your images.

Comment: Let me know if my answer works for you

Comment: May I ask if my answer sufficiently answered you question that you accept it by using the tick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the `CSS Property Clear`. An example in your class might look like this.

```
.gpu {
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    clear:both;
}
```

To get a better idea of how to use `clear` look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp) and see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/4x56xLas/1/) for an example.

**Edit with additional example**

Looking at the images in your question you are probably going to want to use containers. This could be done by wrapping a few pictures in a div and then floating both the image and div. Take a look at this [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/wtLo3Lhk/)

The code in the JSFiddle produces an output which looks like the following.

[image: Image Layout]

*Note: If you are not using a `1920x1080` monitor you might need to resize the running area of JSFiddle to make it look like the desired output*

**Edit 2**

To fix your JSFiddle I just floated all the divs and add a margin to the left to separate them. This is the code I used.

```
.imgs, .leftImgs, .centerImgs, .rightImgs {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

*Note: If you position your `.imgs` class just use the following code instead.*

```
.leftImgs, .centerImgs, .rightImgs {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: That seemed to fix it, but now I'm having trouble with the elements at the right. It looks like this: http://oi66.tinypic.com/2629m4o.jpg _(the code and output is in the link)_

Comment: @DylanVillaruel Instead of floating to the right. Just float it to the left like in the JSFiddle example

Comment: @DylanVillaruel Let me know if you need anymore help

Comment: hello, I am sorry for the late response. But I am still having trouble even if I float everything to the left. It stays in the bottom

Comment: @DylanVillaruel would you be able to post all the relevant code on the question or in a paste bin. Including the css for the containers and the photos?

Comment: @DylanVillaruel Actually first try adding the line `clear: both` or `clear: left` to the `.headset`

Comment: @DylanVillaruel Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/j7znf8b0/2/) and see edit on post

Comment: @DylanVillaruel No problem